# cannot read multiple files

Tags: android, file

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                            intent.setType("*/*");
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

On activity result, I keep getting only one file selected. despite i selected multiple files. why ?

```
List<Uri> files = Utils.getSelectedFilesFromResult(resultData);
              //  resultData.putExtra(EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                System.out.println(resultData.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,false)+"read request code"+files.size());
                for (Uri uris : files) {
                    uri = uris;//Uri.parse(uris.getPath().toString().replaceFirst("files", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()));
                    // file2 = Utils.getFileForUri(uri);
                    // Do something with the result...
                }
```

Comment: [refer this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25722100/2794507) i hope it will help you!

Comment: didnt help.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in `onActivityResult()` :

```
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(data.getClipData() != null) {
            int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)  
                Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here) 
            }
        } else if(data.getData() != null) {
            String imagePath = data.getData().getPath();
            //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try this on your Activity Result,

```
 ClipData clipdata = resultData.getClipData();
 ArrayList<Uri> mUriList = new ArrayList<>(clipdata.getItemCount());
```

Comment: Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE it's working above Sdk18 and print your result data here... And one more thing if u pick single image u need to call resultData.getData() if multiple files use resultData.getClipData();